# Displaying the name of a child category without listing all childs

Tags: wordpress, categories, wp-list-categories

I'm trying to display the name of a child category attached to a post using this function:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('style=none&orderby=id&show_count=0&use_desc_for_title=0&child_of=39&hide_empty=1'); ?>
```

The problem is that it lists all the child category names of parent 39. I would only like to get the category name that is used by the post.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check here? https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-the-child-category-of-a-specific-parent-category

Comment: Thanks! i found the answer there:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Siyah, I found the answer [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-the-child-category-of-a-specific-parent-category)

```
<?php
foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
if (cat_is_ancestor_of(7, $childcat)) {
echo $childcat->cat_name;
}}
?>
```